# Primefaces datatable with inner ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, facelets

I am currently using PrimeFaces and I am quite satisfied with it. But now I am stuck.

I am displaying a p:DataTable with my entities. My entities also have child entities which I also want to display. Each child entity of my parent entity should result in a new row with the data of the parent entity and the data of the child entity.

So something like this:

```
Parent1.A | Parent1.B | Parent1.C | Child1.A | Child1.B
Parent1.A | Parent1.B | Parent1.C | Child2.A | Child2.B
Parent1.A | Parent1.B | Parent1.C | Child3.A | Child3.B
[...]
```

So I tried something like this, but this didn't work..

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.entities}" var="entity">
    <ui:repeat value="#{entity.children}" var="child">
        /* dataTable columns ... */
    </ui:repeat>
</p:dataTable>
```

This code won't show anything unfortunately.. without the inner repeat, the dataTable is displayed (of course without the children entity data..).
How can I achieve this way of data display?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Best regards!

Comment: Is there a way to get the child from the parent ? Something like `parent.getChild()` ?

Comment: Have you looked at the concept of subtable ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf

Comment: As @thomas.g states, use subtable. Otherwise, you will need to use `c:forEach` instead as it works at view build time.

Comment: @thomas.g Just another question: If there are no children and if I use the subtable, the table doesn't display the whole entry. But it is possible that there aren't any child entries, for this case the column(s) with the child values should be just empty. How can I do so??

Comment: you should ask that as a separate question

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think your use case is not handled by the SubTable. But you can do it using the backing bean to adapt your data. I need more space that what's available inside a comment, I'll post you some code if you ask a specific question about your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DataTable - SubTable as in the [official sample here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml)